# How can you use components from the same file in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently developing/learning in an environment that does not facilitate the use of multiple files when developing a web app. Imagine your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript being in a single file

How can I use a component that is written in the same file as the rest of the HTML and TypeScript? What will the `templateUrl` be, and do I still need to `import` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need import to make declarations known to the current file if they are declared outside of the current file. Therefore you don't need to import if it's already in the same file.

TypeScript doesn't hoist classes like it does with variables.

Either ensure that the class you refer to is declared above the code where you use it or use `forwardRef(() => SomeClassBelow)`.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html and [how to access super component class variable into sub component Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422030/how-to-access-super-component-class-variable-into-sub-component-class) for an example.